# Image not uploaded to Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, camera, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload the image to the firebase database. The device clicks an image using the camera and that should be uploaded to the database. This code runs without any errors but it doesn't upload any image to the database. when I run this application it takes to the camera where I'm successfully able to click the image but after that, it doesn't show the progress bar and also the image doesn't upload.

```
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;


public class New extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView lst;
    private Button btn;
    private StorageReference mstr;
    private final static int GALLERY_INTENT=2;
    private final static int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE=1;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ImageView img;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

        //to upload images to database
        mstr = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        img = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            StorageReference filepath = mstr.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

            filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(New.this,"Upload done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Task<Uri> downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                    Picasso.with(New.this).load(String.valueOf(downloadUri)).fit().centerCrop().into(img);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the log of that error!!

Comment: `Uri uri = data.getData();`  No you will not get an uri in onActivityResult as your camera intent is such that you get a thumbnail bitmap of the picture taken.

Comment: You have to request CAMERA permission in manifest. Your post is confusing as the log tells that the camera is not even opened. Hence this is no uploading problem.

Comment: that is not an issue camera does open and even clicks image.

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't upload.

Comment: You might want to add an `addOnFailureListener` to the `filepath.putFille(uri)` call too, and see if you get an error back.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :-

```
StorageReference filepath = mstr.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

UploadTask uploadTask = filepath.putFile(uri);


uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                throw task.getException();
                            }
                            return storageReference.getDownloadUrl();
                        }
                    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                            videoDownloadUrl = String.valueOf(task.getResult());

                            final Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                            map.put("URL",videoDownloadUrl);

                            db.child("").child("").push().setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    //do what ever you want.
                        }
                    });
```